# Automatically toggle html tabs

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following tab structure in the form of a form with a submit button on the second tab. Is it possible for the tabs to auto-change upon a certain condition?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<h3>HOME</h3>
<p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
<h3>Menu 1</h3>
<p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
<h3>Menu 2</h3>
<p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to answer this without knowing what condition you want or seeing any code apart from the HTML structure (and without any CSS).

I'm assuming clicking on the anchors will change tabs, so what you need to do is add ids to them:

```
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" id="tab1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" id="tab2">Menu 2</a></li>
```

and then if you're using jQuery do something like:

```
if(/*whatever condition you want*/){
  $('#tab2').click();
}
```

otherwise:

```
if(/*whatever condition you want*/){
  document.getElementById('tab2').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a multi-step form or a form wizard.

There are multiple examples on google on how to achieve such a solution and many many many JavaScript and jQuery modules/libraries which provide such functionality.

one sample can be found at this JSFiddle by JQ Purfect using bootstrap wizard:
http://jsfiddle.net/JQPurfect/nGnbJ/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
        onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index + 1;
            var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
            $('.bar').text($percent.toFixed(0) + '%');
            $('#rootwizard').find('.bar').css({
                width: $percent + '%'
            });
        }
    });
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
});
```

Or follow this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-simple-wizard

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap tabs javascript reference to manipulate tabs to do something based on a condition.  You can see the javascript reference at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp.  If you are trying to show your tab then you should be able to just use something like the following:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#menu2"]').tab('show')
```

Not knowing what condition you want to toggle the tab on I made a fiddle to show you with just a click function but you can use whatever fucntion you want to show the tab.

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/zxgy4u32/)